# Изменение цвета шрифта QLabel

Tags: python, ооп, gui, pyqt, qlabel

Долго искал в интернете, но не нашел, как изменить через методы `QLabel` шрифт, цвет шрифта и его кегль?

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QFileDialog, \
    QMessageBox, QStyle, QWidget, QPushButton, QLabel


class MyWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyWidget, self).__init__()
        self.setGeometry(250, 250, 300, 300)
        self.setWindowTitle("a")
        self.label1 = QLabel("text", self)
        self.label1.setGeometry(10, 10, 100, 20)

        self.btn1 = QPushButton("red", self)
        self.btn1.setGeometry(100, 10, 50, 50)

        self.btn2 = QPushButton("blue", self)
        self.btn2.setGeometry(200, 10, 50, 50)
        
        self.btn1.clicked.connect(self.make_red)
        self.btn2.clicked.connect(self.make_blue)
        
    def make_red(self):
        pass
    
    def make_blue(self):
        pass
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MyWidget()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Вот условный пример кода, где кнопка `blue` делает текст синим, а `red` красным. 
Как это сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Текстовые виджеты `Qt` могут отображать форматированный текст, заданный с помощью подмножества разметки `HTML 4`. Виджеты, использующие QTextDocument, такие как `QLabel` и QTextEdit, могут отображать форматированный текст, указанный таким образом.

Можно так:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QFileDialog, \
    QMessageBox, QStyle, QWidget, QPushButton, QLabel


class MyWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyWidget, self).__init__()
        self.setGeometry(250, 250, 300, 300)
        self.setWindowTitle("a")
        self.label1 = QLabel("text", self)
        self.label1.setGeometry(10, 10, 100, 20)

        self.btn1 = QPushButton("red", self)
        self.btn1.setGeometry(100, 10, 50, 50)

        self.btn2 = QPushButton("blue", self)
        self.btn2.setGeometry(200, 10, 50, 50)
        
        self.btn1.clicked.connect(self.make_red)
        self.btn2.clicked.connect(self.make_blue)
        
    def make_red(self):
        self.label1.setText("<span style='color: #f00;'>text</span>")
    
    def make_blue(self):
        self.label1.setText("<span style='color: #00f;'>text</span>")
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MyWidget()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]